# WTP Eclipse JavaScript editor - how to add context menu items?

Tags: eclipse, editor, eclipse-wtp

I've been unable to discover how to add right-click popup context menu items to the WTP 3.2.x (JS) JavaScript editor for my plug-in.

In the past I've extended this type of functionality via an editor ID.

In the manifest using the extension org.eclipse.ui.editorActions I am able to add menu-bar items using the ID 'org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor'.

In the manifest using the extension org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus none of the things I have tried have allowed me to add context menu items.

I am hoping someone with more knowledge of the inner workings of the new WTP JavaScript editor(s) will be willing to offer some advice.

Perhaps someone from the WTP team might be able to comment on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try #JavaScriptEditorContext, as set in the CompilationUnitEditor's constructor.

Comment: Hi Nitind - thanks for taking the time to answer this!  I eventually figured this out but but forgot to come back and update.  I don't have enough reputation yet to give you vote up so this thanks will have to do. :)